# How can I have a ComboBox retain the recently entered values?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a WinForms program in c# that features a text field that I would like to replace with an editable ComboBox.

The effect I would like to achieve is similar to the OpenFileDialog, or to some extent the Address bar in Windows Explorer. That is, when you enter in a valid item, that item is added to the list of possible values that the dropdown displays. I would also like this to persist on subsequent runs of the program.

So, basically

1. Program runs for the first time, ComboBox is blank and has nothing in the list
2. User enters a value into ComboBox and hits enter (or a button), value is used and then added to the ComboBox's list
3. User exits program
4. User re-enters program, ComboBox is blank but the value used in the previous session is in the list.

I can imagine several ways to implement this, but it just seems like something for which there might be an easy way to accomplish that I don't know about. Like how someone would implement autocomplete only to discover that the control supported it already.

If not then I can just go ahead with some other way of adding and persisting the information, I was just curious if there was something readymade already.

Comment: Combox has autocomplete feature. The only thing you need to do is to persist the list on storage and retrieve it. (Normal File IO)

Comment: I agree with Steve..and you may rely on Serialization to easily persist the state object instead of dive deep inside the I/O raw operations. Anyway if I were you I'd prefer much more a simple pairs list persisted as key,value\n

Comment: Perhaps this is a job for [user defined settings?](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29130/Windows-Forms-Creating-and-Persisting-Custom-User)

Comment: You can just save the list of searched words as a `System.Collections.Specilized.String.Collection` setting and retrive the values upon application startup.

Comment: OK so I basically went the file I/O route, so if someone would put an answer with that I'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

From the properties list of the comboBox you can choose the DropDownStyle as DropDown and from the Misc choose the autocompletemode to (suggest) or (appened).

when user enter something, it will be saved, and when he runs the app in the next time, you should fill the comboBox with the options or give a custom source from the misc too.